# ASP.Net modal page code behind not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, modal-dialog

I have an asp.net app that launches a modal window upon button_click event. That modal window launches another modal window upon another button_click event.

However, the final modal window's "Page_Load" event is not firing.

The second modal winodw is called via a javascript call from vb.net code behind  `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Script", "ShowModalWin('brPreview','brPreview')", True)`

Any ideas?

Comment: *"Any ideas?"*: No, because you haven't provided enough informations.

Comment: Is the second modal window opening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt if you can have two modal windows overlay on each other. As a last resort, you can try window.open() to create a popup window. HTH

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide more information.

But my first thought is validation. Are you sure the second button click is not causing the page validators to fire?

Comment: There are no page validators on any of the modal pages. What other information would you need?

Comment: (try putting a causesvalidation="false" on the button)